# Spring Boot multiproject Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datatables, spring-data-jpa

I have a three module Spring Boot App. I've a problem when I try to add a Custom repositoryFactoryBeanClass and when i do that i get the following error:

> *No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean'*

My annotation is:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass =
DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages =
"xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.repositories")
```

I have three modules: web, entity/repository and service.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the dependency you are using  (name and version) for DataTable repository  ?

Comment: Thais one:
    <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>

Comment: I am facing same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I changed @EnableJpaRepositories to 

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.repositories", repositoryBaseClass = DataTablesRepositoryImpl.class)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally,I changed @EnableJpaRepositories to

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.repositories", repositoryBaseClass = DataTablesRepositoryImpl.class)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by upgrading Spring Boot version to 1.5.4.RELEASE. Please refer this thread for more details https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/issues/50